# prove f+g uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

Suppose the functions $f$ and $g$  are uniformly continuous on $D$. prove that $f+g$ is also uniformly continuous continuous on $D$. Show that $f⋅g$ is not necessarily uniformly continuous by a suitable example.

I proved that $f+g$ is uniformly continuous but i'm not sure I posted my attempt please read it I want to make sure that it is correct, but I need help with the example for $f⋅g$. thank you.

Comment: You have insert some brackets to make your argument more readable.

Comment: i don't know what brackets do you mean?

Comment: $f+g(x)-f+g(y)$ makes little sense. You should write it as $(f+g)(x)-(f+g) (y)$.

Comment: oh okay. i'll make sure to fix that. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your proof for $f+g$ is correct. For $fg$ take $f(x)=g(x)=x$ on $\mathbb R$.

To show that $x^{2}$ is not uniformly continuous consider the points $n, n+\frac 1 n$.